# pandas stack find unique on combination of two columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find unique values in **Field1**, **Field2** along with the sum of corresponding values from **Value1**, **Value2**.

Please find below the sample input and output. I tried using stack but was unable to get the similar output.

### Input

```
id  Field1  Value1  Field2  Value2
1     A       1       B       0
1     A       0     
2     A       1       D       1
3     C       1       A       0
4     E       0     
3     A       1       C       1
4     F       1
```

### Output

```
id  Field   Value
1     A       1
1     B       0     
2     A       1
2     D       1
3     C       2
3     A       1
4     E       0
4     F       1
```

I am trying to remove rows if the column contains a specific value along with others.

For example in the above output, I will remove rows with **A,B** if they appear along with others and will print them if they appear standalone. Please see below the new output

### Output2

```
id  Field   Value
1     A       1
1     B       0     
2     D       1
3     C       2
4     E       0
4     F       1
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to sum the values as part of the process; adding an explanation on what you are trying to achieve makes it simpler to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with `groupby` and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Field', 'Value'], i='index', j='id')
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .groupby(by=['id', 'Field'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum())
```

Alternative with `lreshape`, but still not in oficial [docs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003):

```
df = (pd.lreshape(df, {'Value':['Value1','Value2'], 'Field':['Field1','Field2']})
        .groupby(['id', 'Field'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum())

print (df)
   id Field  Value
0   1     A    1.0
1   1     B    0.0
2   2     A    1.0
3   2     D    1.0
4   3     A    1.0
5   3     C    2.0
6   4     E    0.0
7   4     F    1.0
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Added a new issue. Could you please check it out? Thnks in advance

Comment: I want to delete rows with 'A' & 'B' only if for a given id if they appear along with other values(as in case of id=2,3). I will keep them if they dont appear with other values(as in the case of id=1)
Thanks

Comment: @Nani - Can you create new question? It seems more complicated.